# Highcharts change legend of only last stacked value

Tags: highcharts

I have a highchart, as showed on the appended image. 
I am attempting to format the legend of only my last data stacked. In this case, index 1 always.
Any help on how to achieve this?
[image]

My main goal, being, on there always showing a value i have in a variable, which will be the max value possible.

```
createChart: function (id, chartData, maxYValues, chartTitle, chartNames, dataToMax) {
    var me = this;
    debugger;
    me.highChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            renderTo: id
        },
        title: {
            text: chartTitle,
            fontSize: '8px'
        },
        xAxis: {
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            },
            categories: chartNames
        },
        yAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: maxYValues
            },
            title: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        colors: ['#afafaf', '#f89c1c', '#3aaa80'],
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span>{point.name}</span>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                colors: ['#3aab80', '#3aab80'],
                colorByPoint: true,
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    headerFormat: '{point.y + point.name}',
                    format: '{y} mb',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    y: -20
                }
            },
            column: {
                stacking: "percent"
            },
            area: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            labelFormat: '<b>{point.y} MB</b><br/>',
            labelFormatter: function () {
                if (me.series.data.index === 1) {
                    return maxYValues;
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            showInLegend: false,
            data: chartData,
            color: '#3aab80'
        }, {
            showInLegend: false,
            data: dataToMax,
            legend: {
                labelFormat: maxYValues + 'MB</b><br/>'
            }
        }],
        navigation: {
            menuItemStyle: {
                fontSize: '8px'
            }
        }
    });
},
```

Thank you
UPDATE: Added code snipped, and updated the image to what my current code is showing

Comment: you forgot the image

Comment: @RahulSharma God, this was ridiculously stupid on my behalf. Sorry, and thanks

Comment: Do you mean the legend, or the axis label?  Do you have a fiddle or code example of your chart?

Comment: @jlbriggs Updated with my code. Basically, i want to show on top of the stacks, the total value of the stacks.

Comment: It looks like you are already doing that. What is the part that you need help with?

Comment: so you want to show the number 100 right?

Comment: In this case, it is the number 100. But in truth. It is a variable i want to show